# WiX 3.8; Desktop shortcut depending on chosen feature

Tags: wix, shortcut-file

I'm struggling on creating a desktop-shortcut depending on the chosen feature(s) within the WiX-Installer. If I run the installer, no shortcut is appearing. Is doesn't matter if only one feature is chosen or both. Are there any ideas out there?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<Product Id="XXX" Name="MyProduct" Language="1031" Codepage="1252" Version="4.4.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="XXX">
    <Package Description="MyProductDescription" Comments="someText" InstallerVersion="400" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Languages="1031"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="application.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="high"/>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
            <Directory Name="LfF" Id="INSTALLDIR">
                <Directory Id="BIN" Name="bin"/>
                    <Component Id="App1.exe" Directory="BIN" Guid="XXX">
                        <File Id="App1.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.src)\App1.exe" />
                    </Component>
                    <wix:Component Id="DesktopShortcutApp1" Directory="DesktopFolder" Guid="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
                        <wix:Shortcut Id="desktopShortcutApp1" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="App1.exe" Target="[App1.exe]" WorkingDirectory="BIN" Icon="DesktopIconApp1.exe" IconIndex="0" />
                        <wix:RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\App1_Desktop_Shortcut" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" />
                    </wix:Component>
                    <Component Id="App2.exe" Directory="BIN" Guid="XXX">
                        <File Id="App2.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.src)\App2.exe" />
                    </Component>
                    <wix:Component Id="DesktopShortcutApp2" Directory="DesktopFolder" Guid="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
                        <wix:Shortcut Id="desktopShortcutApp2" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="App2.exe" Target="[App2.exe]" WorkingDirectory="BIN" Icon="DesktopIconApp2.exe" IconIndex="0" />
                        <wix:RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\App2_Desktop_Shortcut" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" />
                    </wix:Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyProductName">
                <Component Id="StartMenuShortcuts" Guid="XXX">
                    <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall"/>
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value=""/>
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="App1" Level="1" Title="App1" TypicalDefault="advertise">
        <ComponentRef Id="App1.exe" />
        <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcutApp1" />
    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="App2" Level="1" Title="App2" TypicalDefault="advertise">
        <ComponentRef Id="App2.exe" />
        <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcutApp2"/>
    </Feature>
    <UI>
    </UI>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="..\src\bannerapp.bmp"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="..\src\dialogapp.bmp"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree_NoLicense"/>
    <Icon Id="DesktopIconApp1.exe" SourceFile="$(var.src)\App1.exe"/>
    <Icon Id="DesktopIconApp2.exe" SourceFile=".$(var.src)\App2.exe"/>            
</Product>
```

The script is a shortened version of the original one. Content of the `Directory Id="BIN"` is generated through heat.exe and modified with xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and error I've found a solution.

1. make the shortcut element to a child of the component containig the file element
2. make the icon element to a child of the shortcut element
3. set the `Level="32767"` and `TypicalDefault="install"` in each feature (which means: Do not install that feature)

During the setup process choose the feature(s) you want to install and only for this/these the desktopshortcut will be created.

And here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Product Id="XXX" Name="MyProduct" Language="1031" Codepage="1252" Version="4.4.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="XXX">
        <Package Description="MyProductDescription" Comments="someText" InstallerVersion="400" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Languages="1031"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="application.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="high"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Name="LfF" Id="INSTALLDIR">
                    <Directory Id="BIN" Name="bin"/>
                        <Component Id="App1.exe" Directory="BIN" Guid="XXX">
                            <File Id="App1.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.src)\App1.exe" />
                            <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcutApp1" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="App1.exe" WorkingDirectory="BIN" Advertise="yes">
                                <Icon Id="DesktopApp1.ico" SourceFile="$(var.src)/App1.ico" />
                            </Shortcut>
                        </Component>
                        <Component Id="App2.exe" Directory="BIN" Guid="XXX">
                            <File Id="App2.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.src)\App2.exe" />
                            <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcutApp2" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="App2.exe" WorkingDirectory="BIN" Advertise="yes">
                                <Icon Id="DesktopApp2.ico" SourceFile="$(var.src)/App2.ico" />
                            </Shortcut>
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyProductName">
                    <Component Id="StartMenuShortcuts" Guid="XXX">
                        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall"/>
                        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value=""/>
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="App1" Level="32767" Title="App1" TypicalDefault="install">
            <ComponentRef Id="App1.exe" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="App2" Level="32767" Title="App2" TypicalDefault="install">
            <ComponentRef Id="App2.exe" />
        </Feature>
        <UI>
        </UI>
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.src)/bannerapp.bmp"/>
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.src)/dialogapp.bmp"/>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree_NoLicense"/>    
    </Product>
</Wix>
```